# Verifying complete Mapping of an [unordered] Collection/Set of Items in a Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit.net, semantic-comparison

I'm using xUnit.net, AutoFixture and SemanticComparison and want to verify the results of a mapping.

[On the individual item level, I'm well covered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714258/likeness-as-resemblance-polishing-and-packaging/16714559#16714559).

Given

- The items share an identifying key
- I want to do a comparison on the value elements on both side
- I don't care about ordering (and don't want my Assertion to break under re-ordering)

How do I verify that each and every input item maps to one and only one output item in a [DAMP yet DRY manner](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=advanced-unit-testing) using as much OOTB componentry as possible ?

Fixtures:

```
class Input
{ 
   public string Name, Description;
}

class Output
{ 
   public string Name, Description, IgnoreThisField;
}
```

Skeleton Test:

```
[Theory,AutoData]
void MappingWorks( Mapper sut, Input[] inputs)
{
    var outputs = sut.Map( inputs);

    // TODO assert that every input is mapped
    // TODO assert that we have have no extra outputs
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a [[very neat] FullOuterJoin operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13503860/11635) and xUnit.net V2, you can express it as:

```
static void VerifyFeaturesetFullyMapped(
    IEnumerable<Output> outputs,
    IEnumerable<Input> inputs )
{
    Assert.All(
        inputs.FullOuterJoin( outputs,
            f => f.Item1, r => r.Name,
            ( x, y, key ) => new { 
                InDescription = x.Item2, 
                OutDescription = y.Description } ),
        inout =>
            Assert.Equal( inout.InDescription, inout.OutDescription ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given some `AssertResemblance.Like` Collection helpers[1], you

1. Put them in the same order (which is most cleanly done in the test body as the input and output collections will be of different types and unless `SemanticComparison` grows a feature I don't think it can be usefully generalised)
2. Let `Ploeh.SemanticComparison`'s `Likeness` do the matching on `Name`
3. Let xUnit.net V2's Assert.Collection do the correlation (it doesn't yet give a greate message)

Final result is:

```
var results = from result in outputs orderby result.Name select result;

var expectations = from input in inputs orderby input.Name select input;
AssertResemblance.Like( expectations, results, 
   configure=>configure
      .Without(x=>x.IgnoreThisField) );
```

---

[1]

```
static class AssertResemblance
{
    public static void Like<T, T2>( IEnumerable<T> expected, IEnumerable<T2> actual )
    {
        Like<T, T2>( expected, actual, x=>x );
    }

    public static void Like<T, T2>( IEnumerable<T> expected, IEnumerable<T2> actual, Func<Likeness<T, T2>, Likeness<T, T2>> configureLikeness )
    {
        Assert2.Collection( actual, SelectShouldEqualAsAction( expected.Select( x => configureLikeness( x.AsSource().OfLikeness<T2>() ) ) ) );
    }

    public static void Like<T>( IEnumerable<T> expected, IEnumerable<T> actual, Func<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>> unify )
    {
        Like<T>( expected, actual, unify, x=>x );
    }

    public static void Like<T>( IEnumerable<T> expected, IEnumerable<T> actual, Func<IEnumerable<T>,IEnumerable<T>> unify, Func<Likeness<T, T>, Likeness<T, T>> configureLikeness )
    {
        Assert2.Collection( unify( actual ), SelectShouldEqualAsAction( unify(expected).Select( x => configureLikeness( x.AsSource().OfLikeness<T>() ) ) ) );
    }

    static Action<TDestination>[] SelectShouldEqualAsAction<TSource, TDestination>( IEnumerable<Likeness<TSource, TDestination>> that )
    {
        return (from it in that select (Action<TDestination>)it.ShouldEqual).ToArray();
    }
}
```