# Equality test for a record type with generated fields

Tags: f#, tdd

If a record type includes generated fields such as an auto-generated id and a timestamp, e.g.:

```
type UserCreated = {
    Id: Guid
    Name: string
    CreationTime: Instant
}
```

what is the best way to write unit tests against this? It is not possible to simply assert that the record is equal to any particular value, because it cannot be known in advance what the Id and CreationTime values will be.

Possible solutions:

- Make individual assertions for each field
- pass a function into the user creation function that handles generation of ids and dates. Unit tests could then inject a stub function that returns pre-determined values. Or indeed make callers pass in an id and timestamp directly.
- Use some sort of lenses library
- Never auto-generate anything, with the client deciding all fields in advance
- Use a custom equality comparer (this doesn't sound like a good idea at all)
- Something else?

What is considered the best way to do this?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284177/verifying-a-set-of-objects-have-been-mapped-correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach would indeed be to pass a function into the user creation function that handles generation of ids and dates. If there are too many parameters that you have to pass in, then that's probably a clue that you need to refactor your design.

Here's the domain layer, for example:

```
// =================
// Domain
// =================
open System

type UserCreated = {
    Id: Guid
    Name: string
    CreationTime: DateTime
}

// the generation functions are passed in
let createCompleteRecord generateGuid generateTime name = 
    {
        Id = generateGuid()
        Name = name  // add validation?
        CreationTime = generateTime()
    }
```

In the application code, you'd use partial application to bake in the generators and create a useful function `createRecord`

```
// =================
// Application code
// =================
let autoGenerateGuid() = Guid.NewGuid()
let autoGenerateTime() = DateTime.UtcNow

// use partial application to get a useful version
let createRecord = createCompleteRecord autoGenerateGuid autoGenerateTime

let recForApp = createRecord "myname"
```

In the test code, you'd use partial application to bake in other generators and create a different function `createRecordForTesting`

```
// =================
// Test code
// =================

let explicitGenerateGuid() = Guid.Empty
let explicitGenerateTime() = DateTime.MinValue

// use partial application to get a useful version
let createRecordForTesting = createCompleteRecord explicitGenerateGuid explicitGenerateTime

let recForTest = createRecordForTesting "myname"

Assert.AreEqual(Guid.Empty,recForTest.Id)
Assert.AreEqual("myname",recForTest.Name)
Assert.AreEqual(DateTime.MinValue,recForTest.CreationTime)
```

and since the "generated" fields now have hard-coded values, you can also test the whole record equality logic too:

```
let recForTest1 = createRecordForTesting "myname"
let recForTest2 = createRecordForTesting "myname"
Assert.AreEqual(recForTest1,recForTest2)
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't considered partial application, clearly I'm still not thinking functionally enough!

Answer (score 3):

You don't really test the record type itself - it's just dumb data. What you want to test are functions that operate on that data.

A function is simple to test when it's pure. Both calling `Guid.NewGuid()` and `DateTime.Now`, which is what I assume you do for the two problematic fields here, are side effects. So refactoring those two bits out into functions you pass in explicitly as arguments would be the way to go in my book (your bullet point 2). It would make the code simpler to test and a bit more pure (perhaps a bit less readable as well, I guess you need to balance that).

That said - for most test cases that would involve your record you should know the values of those fields when you arrange the test. It's only when you test the function that creates the record 'from nothing' that you don't know them beforehand, and for that case you could just check if the `Name` field has the expected value (so your bullet point 1 where necessary, comparing records 'as is' everywhere else).

**Edit**: I don't know if you missed it or not, but one other possibility is to define a dedicated comparison function in the test project, and ensure the 'generated' values are the same in both records before comparing them:

```
let compareWithoutGenerated (a: UserCreated) (b: UserCreated) = 
    a = { b with Id = a.Id; CreationTime = a.CreationTime }
```

And then:

```
WhateverUnit.Assert.True(compareWithoutGenerated a b)
```

Obviously this is uglyish, but I would say it's fair game for tests. Arguably there are better ways to do it, but at the very least, this one doesn't inflict test-induced damage on your production code.

Comment: My example is maybe a bit too basic in that there is only one non-generated field, so it looks obvious to simply assert on the value of Name, but as a general rule such a strategy would result in numerous assertions on different fields.

I have done (2) and passed in each creation function as an extra parameter, but as you say it does make the code less readable. I was just wondering if there was some standard way to do this that I had missed.

Comment: @junichiro: Fair enough, if there was more than say 3 fields left to compare, I would probably extract the comparison to a function. Edited the answer with a trick to handle that.

Comment: I wasn't really sure whether it was normal to pass in every single side-effect producing function as a parameter, as it seems kind of messy. I think I personally prefer mapping the record type using "with", because as you say the mess is in the tests, not the code.